# UrhoSharp Xamarin.Form - Unable to load dll 'mono-urho'

Tags: c#, dll, uwp, xamarin.forms, urhosharp

I've impelemented custom control for my Xamarin.Forms project and I have problem trying to start UrhoSharp engine for UWP platform.

The issues arises at `Run()` method called on `UrhoSufrace` control:

```
// this _engine object is my custom object with some application options
Control.Run<SceneEngine.EngineApplication>(_engine.EngineApplicationOptions);
```

There is [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39894134/urhosharp-forms-on-uwp-unable-to-load-dll-mono-urho) already but it does not solve my problem.

The exception I get: `Unable to load DLL 'mono-urho': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)`

```
 at Urho.Sdl.SDL_SetMainReady()
 at Urho.UWP.UrhoSurface.Run(Type appType, ApplicationOptions options)
 at Urho.UWP.UrhoSurface.Run[TGame](ApplicationOptions options)
 at IM01App.UWP.Controls.Engine3dRenderer.<OnElementChanged>d__2.MoveNext()
```

I've already tried to use different verions of UrhoSharp.

I've also checked if the `mono-urho.dll` file exists and it can be found in the UWP project directory at `bin\x86\`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was such that the path to the `mono-urho.dll` had spaces:

```
UWP\bin\x86\UWP - Visualization only\mono-urho.dll
UWP\bin\x86\UWP - Visualization only\Urho.dll
UWP\bin\x86\UWP - Visualization only\AppX\mono-urho.dll
UWP\bin\x86\UWP - Visualization only\AppX\Urho.dll
```

I had configuration with name: `UWP - Visualization only`.
Changing it to: `Debug` solved this issue:

```
UWP\bin\x86\Debug\mono-urho.dll
UWP\bin\x86\Debug\Urho.dll
UWP\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\mono-urho.dll
UWP\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\Urho.dll
```